# Complex search screens in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I need to implement some search functionality within a Rails application.  Most of the stuff I have found is generally aimed at simple plain-text search.  I am trying to implement something much more specific.  The sort of functionality I am looking to create is this (from a C application):

http://andyc.ac/query.gif

The form just submits the data entered by the user.  So I need to translate strings like "3..7" into SQL conditions for the where method e.g.

```
TestLine.where( "test_int >= ? and test_int <= ?", MinInt, MaxInt )
```

It seems like this is something that already exists somewhere.  The exact format expected is not too important, as the users are not shared between the Rails and C applications.  How would this be done?

Comment: why not use scope in your model?

Comment: Awesome question with the diagram included. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW the specific functionality you describe is actually supported directly. Well.. almost. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> A range may be used in the hash to use the SQL `BETWEEN` operator:
>
> ```
> Student.where(:grade => 9..12)
> ```

Of course then it's a matter of translating the user's string input to a Range, which isn't very complex, e.g.:

```
def str_to_range str
  str =~ /(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/

  Range.new *$~.captures.map(&:to_i)
end
```

It would probably make the most sense in a `scope` on your model. (Of course a shortcut would be to simply `eval '9..12'` but `eval`ing input from the end user is a really, really bad idea.)

Comment: Thanks I am looking into this also: I was a bit hesitant to rewrite the thousands of lines of code in the query lib from the C application, but as I try it, it seems like the bits I need fit into a couple of pages of code!

Comment: This looks like the approach I'm going to go with.  I've found SQLite doesn't like BETWEEN clauses on string fields though (we've got a lot of fields that are strings but mostly numeric) so I'm going to switch databases to get around that issue.

Comment: Be careful doing that, as string comparison and number comparison often act differently. So while `5` may be `BETWEEN 1 AND 10`, `'5'` may or may not be `BETWEEN '1' AND '10'` (think mathematical vs. alphabetical). A workaround is to cast your strings as numbers, e.g. `BETWEEN CAST(str_val AS INT) AND CAST(other_str_val AS INT)`. This would probably save you the trouble of switching database platforms.

Comment: Good point, but by mostly numeric, I mean a string like 'M37012883' (so it won't cast).  On most databases, you can run BETWEEN 'M37012883' AND 'M37012921' and see the IDs in that range, which is hard to do with a wildcard string search.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at thinking sphinx(http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/). It might make your task a lot easier. You can search in that:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#basic

Comment: Thanks, I am currently looking into this.  It looks good, but I'm not sure it is really optimised to allow search on every field of every model.